# How to use stopPropagation with text to speech?

Tags: javascript, android, html, stoppropagation, responsivevoice

I have made a little webpage (and app) in javascript for people with a mental retardation. There are some images to click on. When they do so, they hear a voice saying some text. Now I want to prevent them clicking before the voice has ended speaking. So the voices don't mix up.I want to do this with `Event.stopPropagation()`. How can I do it? Is there a better way?

```js
 function klok()
 { 
 responsiveVoice.cancel();
 var today = new Date();
  var h = today.getHours();
  var m = today.getMinutes();
 var pause = 7000;
  setTimeout(function(){ responsiveVoice.speak(" het is nu "+h+" uur en "+m+" minuten",'Dutch Female', parameters2); },100);
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>MenuView</title>

<script src="https://code.responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice.js"></script>


</head>
<body oncontextmenu="return false;">

<p STYLE="text-align: center;">
<img id="myimage" onmousedown="klok()" src="klok.jpg" width=20% height=auto //>
</p>

<script>
function voiceStartCallback() {
    console.log("Voice started");
  color = "red";
    document.body.style.background = color;
}
function voiceEndCallback() {
    console.log("Voice ended");
  color = "black";
    document.body.style.background = color;
}
function voiceEndCallback2() {
    console.log("Voice ended");
  color = "white";
    document.body.style.background = color;
}
var parameters = {
    onstart: voiceStartCallback,
    onend: voiceEndCallback
}
var parameters2 = {
    onstart: voiceStartCallback,
    onend: voiceEndCallback2
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```